# How to implement different query in each iteration of a foreach loop?

Tags: php, jquery, database, codeigniter, foreach

I am trying to dynamically populate different tables on the same page from db! The problem comes when I sum the item quantity in the the end of each table! The Sum of quantity is correct for the first table but add the previous quantity in the next table's total quantity! kindly help me in this regard that how can I implement different query in each repeating div of foreach loop, or is there anything else that i can do!
there goes my code :

```
<?php foreach ($items as $row): ?>
<!-- Tab Contents Starts -->
<div class="tab-content">
   <div id="list" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <!-- NEW TABLE -->
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="clearfix">
               <div class="pull-right tableTools-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-header" style="background:<?php echo $color; ?>!important;">
               <td><?php echo $row->name; ?> </td>
               <button class="green ace-icon fa fa-caret-down bigger-120" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $row->name; ?>" style="float: right;"></button>
            </div>
            <!-- div.table-responsive -->
            <!-- div.dataTables_borderWrap -->
            <div>
               <table id="dynamic-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Material Name</th>
                        <th>Available Quantity</th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->quantity; ?> </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" class="collapse">
      <div class="tab-content">
         <div id="list" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <!-- NEW TABLE -->
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div class="clearfix">
                     <div class="pull-right tableTools-container"></div>
                  </div>
                  <?php
                     $rand = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
                     $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];

                     ?>
                  <div class="table-header" style="background:#66C22D!important;">
                     <?php echo $row->name; ?> Invoice List
                  </div>
                  <!-- div.table-responsive -->
                  <!-- div.dataTables_borderWrap -->
                  <div>
                     <table id="dynamic-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                           <tr>
                              <th class="center">Invoice ID</th>
                              <th>Material Name</th>
                              <th>Quantity</th>
                              <th>Total Price</th>
                              <th>Vendor</th>
                              <th>Vendor Contact</th>
                              <th>Purchase Date</th>
                              <th>Action</th>
                           </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <?php $itemname =  $row->name; ?>
                           <?php $groups = $this->db->get_where('raw' , array('material_name' => $itemname) )->result();
                              foreach ($groups as $row): ?>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="center">
                                 <?php echo $row->invoice_id; ?>
                              </td>
                              <td><?php echo $row->material_name; ?> </td>
                              <td>
                                 <?php echo $row->qty;
                                    $totalqty  =$totalqty+ $row->qty;
                                    ?>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                 <?php echo $row->price; ?>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                 <?php echo $row->vendor; ?>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                 <?php echo $row->phone; ?>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                 <?php echo $row->dop; ?>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                 <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs action-buttons">
                                    <!--
                                       <a class="blue" href="#">
                                           <i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i>
                                       </a>  -->
                                    <a class="green" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/raw_crud/do_update/<?php echo $row->id;?>" >
                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="red" href="#" onclick="confirm_modal('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/raw_crud/delete/<?php echo $row->id;?>');">
                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i>
                                    </a>
                                 </div>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                           <tr>
                              <th></th>
                              <th></th>
                              <th></th>
                              <th></th>
                              <th></th>
                              <th></th>
                              <th style="text-align:right">Total Quantity :</th>
                              <th style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $totalqty; ?></th>
                           </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                     </table>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Tab Contents Ends -->
      </div>
      <!-- Tab Contents Ends -->
   </div>
   <!-- Tab Contents Ends -->
</div>
<!-- /.col -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: $totalqty  should be assigned value 0 at the end of the foreach loop but inside the loop. So that for next iteration $totalqty is set to 0.

Comment: set $totalqty = 0 before the second foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Please replace just table code ie. from table start to table end, your issue will be resolved.

```
 <table id="dynamic-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                          <th class="center">Invoice ID</th>
                          <th>Material Name</th>
                          <th>Quantity</th>
                          <th>Total Price</th>
                          <th>Vendor</th>
                          <th>Vendor Contact</th>
                          <th>Purchase Date</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       <?php $itemname =  $row->name; ?>
                       <?php $groups = $this->db->get_where('raw' , array('material_name' => $itemname) )->result();
                       <?php $totalqty = 0; ?>
                          foreach ($groups as $row): ?>
                       <tr>
                          <td class="center">
                             <?php echo $row->invoice_id; ?>
                          </td>
                          <td><?php echo $row->material_name; ?> </td>
                          <td>
                             <?php echo $row->qty;
                                $totalqty  += $row->qty;
                                ?>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                             <?php echo $row->price; ?>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                             <?php echo $row->vendor; ?>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                             <?php echo $row->phone; ?>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                             <?php echo $row->dop; ?>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                             <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs action-buttons">
                                <!--
                                   <a class="blue" href="#">
                                       <i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i>
                                   </a>  -->
                                <a class="green" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/raw_crud/do_update/<?php echo $row->id;?>" >
                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a class="red" href="#" onClick="confirm_modal('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/raw_crud/delete/<?php echo $row->id;?>');">
                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i>
                                </a>
                             </div>
                          </td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                       <tr>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th style="text-align:right">Total Quantity :</th>
                          <th style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $totalqty; ?></th>
                       </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                 </table>
```

Comment: thankyou everyone for your contributions, it worked for me by applying select_sum('qty')  query with get_where clause in footer!